# How to set the default colors in ColorPicker?

Tags: swiftui

The standard SwiftUI's ColorPicker has a set of default colors, take a look:

[image: ColorPicker]

How can I, as developer, set/change them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. That section is for the user to add their own frequently used/favourite colors. They can do this by clicking the "+" button, and the currently selected color will be added to the list. Long-tapping on one of the colors in the list will show up a menu option to delete it.

This list of colors is synchronised across all the color pickers, in all the apps on the user's device. For example, the user can add a new color to the list in your app, and find that newly added color in the Photos app, when marking up their photos.

In a way, this is kind of like selecting a photo from the user's photo library. You cannot add your own images for the user select when the user is using a `PhotosPicker`.

That said, it is possible to filter out all the colors with opacity in the user's list by passing `supportsOpacity: false`.